# Looking for an open-source flatfile/xml database C++ library

Tags: c++, database, open-source, flat-file

I'm looking for a light-weight database library that I can compile into a C++ application.

Does any such exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For pure XML embedded database you might want to peek at [Oracle Berkeley DB XML](http://www.oracle.com/database/berkeley-db/xml/index.html).

Comment: This appears to be exactly what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/). Not flat-file, but it is file based, can be easily embedded in apps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :) . 

SQLite is clearly the most popular choice on stack overflow :P ... +1

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this very lightweight XML library can also be of help: [RapidXML](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/). It's an XML parser, not a database library, but depending on your application that might be enough (you mention a flatfile XML data storage).

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at berkleyDB

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB):

> Berkeley DB (BDB) is a computer
>   software library that provides a
>   high-performance embedded database,
>   with bindings in C, C++, Java, Perl,
>   Python, Ruby, Tcl, Smalltalk, and many
>   other programming languages. BDB
>   stores arbitrary key/data pairs as
>   byte arrays, and supports multiple
>   data items for a single key. BDB can
>   support thousands of simultaneous
>   threads of control or concurrent
>   processes manipulating databases as
>   large as 256 terabytes, on a wide
>   variety of operating systems including
>   most Unix-like and Windows systems,
>   and real-time operating systems.